# ActiveRecord Associations - Where to put functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm looking for some best-practice advice for the following situation.

I have the following skeleton ActiveRecord models:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_entries, dependent: destroy
end

# country_entry.rb
class CountryEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :code, presence: true
end
```

Now suppose I need to get a comma-separated list of `CountryEntry` codes for a particular user.  The question is, where do I put this method?  There are two options:

```
# user.rb
#...
  def country_codes
    self.country_entries.map(&:code)
  end
#...
```

-or-

```
# country_entry.rb
#...
  def self.codes_for_user(user)
    where(user_id: user.id).map(&:code)
  end
#...
```

And so the APIs would be: 
`@current_user.country_codes` -or- `CountryEntry.codes_for_user(@current_user)`

Seems like placing the code in `country_entry.rb` decouples everything a little more, but it makes the API a little uglier.  Any general or personal-experience best practices on this issue?

Answer (score 4):

1. Instance method VS Class method: If the method is for an instance, of course it is better to be an instance method.
2. In user model VS in Coutry model: User model wins. Law of Demeter suggests one dot only in Ruby. If you have chance to do that, of course it's better to follow.

Conclusion: Your first method wins.

```
# user.rb
def country_codes
  self.country_entries.map(&:code)
end
```

#### Add: Reference for Law of Demeter

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/15-the-law-of-demeter

http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/

Comment: I was just about to post exactly the same thing when I saw you'd addd your answer. +1 for being a great mind :)

Comment: Thanks @iain, I just follow great minds but don't own it:) cheers for the common opinion.

Comment: Billy, could you add a reference to your principle? Not sure about what you exactly refer to.

Comment: @EricPlaton, actually the principle is "Law of Demeter" though the basic is similar to Single Responsibility Principle. Check my update for reference.

Comment: I agree with you for this small example.  My only problem is that if this got a little more complicated, the user model would "know" more about the country_entry model.

Comment: @Ryan, no worries at all. User class doesn't care how complicated it is in Country model, it just consumes the API provided by Country, with one level only.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is really an interesting question. And it has so many answers ;-)

From your initial question I would suggest you put the code in the association itself

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_entries do
    def codes
      proxy_association.owner.country_entries.map(&:code)
    end
  end
end
```

so you could do something like this

```
list_of_codes = a_user.country_entries.codes
```

Now obviously this is a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).
So you would best be advised to offer a method on the User object like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_entries do
    def codes
      proxy_association.owner.country_entries.map(&:code)
    end
  end

  def country_codes
    self.country_entries.codes
  end
end
```

Obviously nobody in the Rails world cares about the Law of Demeter so take this with a grain of salt.

As for putting the code into the CountryEntry class I am not sure why you would do this. If you can look up country codes only with the user I dont see the need to create a class method. You are anyway only able to look that list up if you have a User at hand.

If however many different objects can have a country_entries association than it makes sense to put it as a class method into CountryEntry.

My favorite would be a combination of LOD and a class method for reuse purposes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_entries

  def country_codes
    CountryEntry.codes_for_user(self)
  end
end

class CountryEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :code, presence: true

  def self.codes_for_user(some_id)
     where(ref_id: some_id).map(&:code)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of API developers get from the two proposals, adding to the user model seems pretty straightforward. Given the problem:

> Now suppose I need to get a comma-separated list of CountryEntry codes for a particular user.

The context is made of a user, for which we want to get the code list. The natural "entry point" seems a user object.

Another way to see the problem is in terms of responsibilities (thus linking to @robkuz entry on Demeter's). A `CountryEntry` instance is responsible for providing its code (and maybe a few other things). A `CountryEntry` class is basically responsible for providing attributes and methods common to all its instances, and no more (well). Getting the list of comma-separated codes is a specialized usage of `CountryEntry` instances that only `User` objects care of apparently. In this case, the responsibility belongs to the current user object. Value in the eye of the beholder...

This is inline with most answers on the thread, although in the solutions so far, you do not get a comma-separated list of codes, but an array of codes.

---

In terms of performance, note there is probably a difference too because of lazy evaluation. Just a note---someone more deeply familiar with ActiveRecord could comment on that!

Answer (score 0):

I think `@current_user.country_codes` is a better choice in this case because it will be easier to use in your code.